# Ascii characters in window.open();

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to use window.open(); to open a new window and to add parameters to the end of the URL. However when I enter curly braces {} it converts it to the hex code (%7b and %7d).

Does anyone know how to actually make these print out in plain text?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")}

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';

function errorMsg() {
    if (**field 1** == "") {
        return "Error please check all fields are completed";
    } else return "";
}

var error = errorMsg();
if (error != ''){
    alert(error);
    console.log('####' + error);
    } else if (error == ''){
    window.open("https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PointMerge.aspx?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_80}&id={!Opportunity.Id}&ESContactid={QVar0}","","width=700,height=450");
}
```

I have tried converting the curly braces to the, usually accepted, oct codes (\173) but I still get the same %7b output :/

p.s my actual code and URL are a lot longer... I just got rid of the crap so it was easier to read :)

Thanks for all comments in advance :)

Comment: You should fix your server-side code to properly handle URL-encoded characters.

Comment: I have created the button in Salesforce... do you know how I would update that or even if I can update that?

Comment: FYI: You'll usually get a faster salesforce specific response at salesforce.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments I have fixed this :)

I was silly and made things too complicated.... decodeURIComponent()

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")}

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';

function errorMsg() {
    if (**field 1** == "") {
        return "Error please check all fields are completed";
    } else return "";
}

var error = errorMsg();

var URL = decodeURIComponent("https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PointMerge.aspx?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_80}&id={!Opportunity.Id}&ESContactid={QVar0}");

if (error != ''){
    alert(error);
    console.log('####' + error);
    } else if (error == ''){
    window.open(URL,"","width=700,height=450");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I would expect your code to work, you can alternativly do it like this:

window.open( {! '"https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PointMerge.aspx?sessionId='+ API.Session_ID +  'serverUrl=' + API.Partner_Server_URL_80 + '&id=' + Opportunity.Id + '&ESContactid=' + {Qvar0} + '","","width=700,height=450"'}  );

Comment: That doesn't work :/ it's not a Salesforce merge field issue... this is a string that is used by Conga Composer/AppExtremes. Once Conga receives the string in it's literal sense ({QVar0}) it converts it to an ID

Comment: Ah, I did not see that mentioned in your question. If the issue is not salesforce related, maybe it is best not tagged as such.